# How calculate the Error for trapezoidal rule if I only have data? (Python)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numerical-integration

I got this array of data and I need to calculate the area under the curve, so I use the **Numpy** library and the **Scipy** library which contain the functions **trapz** in Numpy and **integrate.simps** in Scipy for a Numerical Integration which gave me a really nice result in both cases.

The problem now is, that I need the error for each one or at least the error for the Trapezoidal Rule. The thing is, that the formula for that ask me a function, which obviously I don't have. I have been researching for a way to obtain the error but always return to the same point...

Here are the pages of **scipy.integrate** http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/integrate.html and **trapz** in Numpy http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html I try and see a lot of code about the Numerical Integration and prefer to use the existing ones...

Any ideas please?

Comment: maybe you can give a detailed example for your problem

Comment: There's a problem in your reasoning: If you know both the numerical integral and the exact error then you can just combine the information and you obtain a method that exactly calculates arbitrary integrals. This makes all numerical integration rules obsolete and is thus probably is not possible :)

Comment: @Falko Thanks for the correction, the English is not my native language so thanks :)

Comment: @cel I don't know the exact error, I'm still a newbie in this :(

Comment: @Amy1204, my point is: with no information about how your integrand function `f` behaves, you have no chance of getting even an estimation of the integration error. If you can assume that f is smooth, you can derive an estimation that depends on the derivates. But only data points are simply not enough information for calculating errors.

Comment: @cel Now it all makes sense, thank you for your patience :)

Answer (score 1):

While [cel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2272172/cel) is right that you cannot determine an integration error if you don't know the function, there is something you can do.

You can use [curve fitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting) to fit a function through the available data points. You can then use that function for error estimation.

If you expect the data to fit a certain kind of function like a sine, log or exponential it is good to use that as a basis for curve fitting.

For instance, if you are measuring the drag on a moving car, it is known that this *mostly* proportional to the velocity squared because of air resistance.

However, if you do not have any knowledge about the applicable function then assuming you have N data points, there is a polynomial of the N-1 degree that fits *exactly* though all those data points. Determining such a polynomial from the data is solving a system of lineair equations. See e.g. [polynomial interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_interpolation). You could use this polynomial as an estimate for the unknown real function. Note however that *outside* the range of data points this polynomial might be *wildly inaccurate*.

Comment: Hmh, are you sure that the results you get from this procedure are reasonable? I mean that's basically what numerical integration does in the first place. First fit an interpolation polynomial, then approximate the integral by that polynomial. This looks a little like calculating the difference between two different numerical integration methods, rather than estimating an error.

Comment: @cel If you are using Simpson's rule for integration and if you use a quadratic polynomial you are right. For e.g. trapeziodal integration or any other function the results would be different.

Comment: Ah yes, I guess this approach does make sense and my last comment is not really true as `curve_fit` gives a least_squares estimation and thus is not an interpolation.

Comment: I also tried the **scipy.interpolate** options, cuz I thought will resolve some of the issues I got. Because the type of data I tried a cubic polynomial as function, but when I plot it realize that was a fail.

Comment: @Amy1204 Choosing the right function is important, otherwise you won't get a good fit. Hence my suggestion.